# Why is it that defining boost::shared_ptr of a templated behaves differently than boost::shared_ptr of a non templated class

Tags: c++, templates, boost, compiler-errors, shared-ptr

I was trying to integrate the boost::share_ptr into a pair of templated classes that were originally derived from a boost::asio example I found. When I define a type within one class which is a shared::ptr of that class. I can't seem to reference the type in another templated class. If I remove templates from the code, it all compiles.

This won't compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>

using namespace std;

template <typename TSomething1>
class SomeTemplateT : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<SomeTemplateT<TSomething1> >
{
public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<SomeTemplateT<TSomething1> > Ptr;

    static Ptr Create()
    {
        return Ptr(new SomeTemplateT<TSomething1>());
    }

    SomeTemplateT()
    {
        cout << "SomeTemplateT created" << endl;
    }
};

template <typename TSomething>
class OtherTemplateT
{
public:
    OtherTemplateT()
    {
        // COMPILATION ERROR HERE
        SomeTemplateT<TSomething>::Ptr someTemplate = SomeTemplateT<TSomething>::Create(); 
    }

private:

};
```

The code above yields the following compilation error:

```
src\Templates\main.cpp: In constructor 'OtherTemplateT<TSomething>::OtherTemplateT()':
src\comps\oamp\src\Templates\main.cpp:30: error: expected ';' before 'someTemplate'
```

Taking virtually the same code without templates compiles without difficulty:

```
class SomeTemplateT : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<SomeTemplateT>
{
public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<SomeTemplateT> Ptr;

    static Ptr Create()
    {
        return Ptr(new SomeTemplateT());
    }

    SomeTemplateT()
    {
        cout << "SomeTemplateT created" << endl;
    }
};

class OtherTemplateT
{
public:
    OtherTemplateT()
    {
        SomeTemplateT::Ptr someTemplate = SomeTemplateT::Create();
    }

private:

};
```

Platform information:
I'm using gcc4.4.0 from MinGW on windows XP (Code:Blocks IDE).

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that if I replace the use of the Ptr typedef with the full declaration of the shared ptr:
    boost::shared_ptr
Everything compiles fine.

Also, I can use the type in code outside the of the template.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SomeTemplateT<TSomething>::Ptr` is a *dependent name*; that is, its definition depends on the template parameter. The compiler can't assume that it's a type name unless you say so:

```
typename SomeTemplateT<TSomething>::Ptr someTemplate = SomeTemplateT<TSomething>::Create();
^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: That did it. I have to remember that everytime I get these bizarre errors, throw in typename :-)

Comment: @Lou: It's actually very predictable when you'll get those errors.  If the name of a type has a template parameter, use `typename`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `typename`:

```
typename SomeTemplateT<TSomething>::Ptr someTemplate = SomeTemplateT<TSomething>::Create();
```

This is required to make parsing possible without semantic analysis. Whether `SomeTemplateT<TSomething>::Ptr` is a type or a member is not known until `SomeTemplateT<TSomething>` has been compiled.

Answer (score 1):

A example taken from the C++11 Standard (n3290) that demonstrate why the keyword *typename* (in this context) is useful.
( 14.6 Name resolution [temp.res] )

```
struct A 
{
    struct X { };
    int X;
};

struct B 
{
    struct X { };
};

template<class T> void f(T t) 
{
    typename T::X x;
}

void foo() 
{
    A a;
    B b;
    f(b); // OK: T::X refers to B::X
    f(a); // error: T::X refers to the data member A::X not the struct A::X
}
```